# I want to show a pop up message on successful registration and if fails then show failure message on redirecting on same page

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to show a pop up message on successful registration and if fails then show failure message on redirecting on same page

```
/*=======USER PAGE(REGISTRATION) CONTROLLER======= */   

    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String userHome(EmpMasterModel masterUser,EmpRegisterModel registerUser,Map<String, Object> map)
    {
        String redirectValue="failure";
        if(empMasterService.find(masterUser.getEmpid())!=null)
        {
            if(empRegisterService.find(registerUser.getEmpid())==null)
                    {
                       empRegisterService.create(registerUser);
                       redirectValue="user";
                    }
        }
        return "redirect:"+redirectValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Message you can use RedirectAttributes concept of spring.
[Spring FlashAttribute](http://javabeat.net/flash-attributes-in-spring-mvc-3-1/)

Comment: I used it earlier but ot getting message.. can you post some syntax.??

Comment: please check attach link.